# Form through Email that can be Parsed Using Python

Tags: python, email, file-format

I want to email out a document that will be filled in by many people and emailed back to me. I will then parse the responses using Python and load them into my database.

What is the best format to send out the initial document in?

I was thinking an interactive .pdf but do not want to have to pay for Adobe XI. Alternatively maybe a .html file but I'm not sure how easy it is to save the state of it once its been filled in in order to be emailed back to me. A .xls file may also be a solution but I'm leaning away from it simply because it would not be a particularly professional looking format.

The key points are:

1. Answers can be easily parsed using Python
2. The format should common enough to open on most computers
3. The document should look relatively pleasing to the eye

Answer (score 0):

Send them a web-page with a [FORM section](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.1), complete with some Javascript to grab the contents of the controls and send them to you (e.g. in JSON format) when they press "submit".

Another option is to set it up as a web application. There are several Python web frameworks that could be used for that. You could then e-mail people a link to the web-app.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use Google Docs for the form. Create the form in Google Docs and save the answer in an excel sheet. And then use any python Excel format reader (Google them) to read the file. This way you don't need to parse through mails and will be performance friendly too. Or you could just make a simple form using AppEngine and save the data directly to the database.